# rename the file according PDF title

Tags: perl, pdf, rename, batch-rename

I am trying to write file rename Perl script, for reducing manual efforts. Manually I open the pdf file, copy the title and rename the file name according to the title.

I am writing below code to rename the pdf according to the file title. e.g. SPE-180024-MS is title and pdf should be renamed to that

According to my logic it should rename the file, but the output is not proper

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
#use warnings;

use Cwd;
use File::Basename;
#use File::Copy;
use File::Find;
use PDF::API2;
use CAM::PDF;

my $path1 = getcwd;
open( F6, ">Ref.txt" );

opendir( DIR, $path1 ) or die $!;
my @dots = grep /(.*?)\-(MS)$/, readdir(DIR);
closedir(DIR);

my @file;
my @files;
my $check;
my $err_1;
my $err_2;
my $err_3;

foreach my $file (@dots) {

    #print F6 $file."\n";
    opendir DIR1, $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";
    my @files = sort grep { -f "$file/$_" } readdir DIR1;
    my $data1 = join( ",", <@files> );
    closedir DIR1;

    #print F6 @files."\n";
    my $a = @files;

    if ($data1 =~ m#(((\w+)\-(\d+)\-MS)\.(pdf))#
        #&& $data1=~m#((\w+)\-(\d+)\-MS\.(xml))#) #((.*?)\.xml)#
        ) {

        my $check = $2;

        #print F6 $1."\n";

        if ( $data1 =~ m#(((\w+)\-(\d+)\-MS)\.(xml))# ) {
            my $check1 = $2;
            my $first  = $1;

            if ( $check eq $file || $check1 eq $file ) {

            }
            else {
                #print F6 $file."\tDIFFERENT FILE PRESENT\n";
            }
        }
    }

    foreach my $f1 ( glob("$file/*.xml") ) {

        #print F6 $f1."\n";

        open( FH, '<', $f1 ) or die "Cannot open file: $f1";
        my $data2 = join( "", <FH> );

        #print F6 $data2."\n";

        close FH;

        if ( $data2 =~ m#(<page-count count="(\d+)"/>)# ) {

            my $page = $2;

            #print F6 $f1."\t".$1."\n";

            if ( $f1 =~ m#(.*?)-MS/((.*?)-MS)#s
                #SPE-173391-MS/SPE-173393-MS    #(.*?)\.(.*?)$/s)
                ) {

                my $f11 = $2;

                #print F6 $f11."\n";
                if ( $file eq $f11 ) {

                }
                else {

                    $err_1
                        = $err_1
                        . $file . "\t"
                        . $f11
                        . "\tDIFFERENT XML FILE PRESENT\n";

                    #print F6 $file."\t".$f11."\tDIFFERENT XML FILE PRESENT\n";
                    #print F6 $file."\tDIFFERENT XML FILE PRESENT\n";
                }

                foreach my $f2 ( glob("$file/*.pdf") ) {

                    open( F2, "<$f2" ) or die "Cannot open file: $f2";
                    my $data = join( "", <F2> );
                    close F2;

                    my $xml_list = $data;

                    my $pdf   = PDF::API2->open($f2);
                    my $pages = $pdf->pages;

                    #print F6 $f2."\t".$pages."\n";

                    if ($f2 =~ m#(.*?)-MS/((.*?)-MS)#

                        #/(.*?)\.(.*?)$/s
                        ) {

                        my $f21 = $2;

                        if ( $file eq $f21 ) {

                        }
                        else {

                            $err_2
                                = $err_2
                                . $file . "\t"
                                . $f21
                                . "\tDIFFERENT PDF FILE PRESENT\n";

                            #print F6 $file."\t".$f21."\tDIFFERENT PDF FILE PRESENT\n";
                        }

                        while ( $f11 =~ m/$f21/gs ) {

                            if ( $page !~ m#$pages#s ) {

                                $err_3
                                    = $err_3
                                    . $f1 . "\t"
                                    . $page . "\t"
                                    . $f2 . "\t"
                                    . $pages . "\n";

                                #print F6 $f1."\t".$page."\t".$f2."\t".$pages."\n";

                                $data2 =~ s#<page-count count="$page"\/>#<page-count count="$pages"\/>#gs;

                                open( FH, '>', $f1 ) or die "Cannot open file: $f1";
                                print FH $data2 . "\n";
                                close FH;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

close F6;
```

---

This is the document. The marked heading is what I want.

[image]

Comment: The content stream in the pdf might be filtered (which usually means it is compressed) and thus you can't just use regexp to find the title (it isn't in the "plain text" form and thus it wouldn't match or the match would be some random part of the pdf). To confirm open the pdf in some notepad-like editor and search for the title - you probably won't find it. You need to properly parse the pdf to get the content of the first page and then extract the title from it. I don't have experience with perl so can't help much with that, sorry.

Comment: thanks for information,but can any one help to generate the code to work properly

Comment: Can you maybe use the tool `pdfinfo` (it is part of the poppler tools package) to tell you the title of the PDF?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you mean by title? Is that some text heading on top of the document, or a meta information in the file? Maybe take a screenshot of a file in a PDF viewer, make stuff unreadable that is sensitive and hand-draw a circle around the part you want.

Comment: thanks mark and  simbabque,  i am not using any tool , i am creating script to find the title of pdf file thats in top of the pdf like(eg: SPE-180024-MS) and replace file according that title

Comment: So it is the _heading_ of the document?

Comment: right heading of document

Comment: simbabque chk this path ,providing a image on that path http://i.stack.imgur.com/o00Kg.png,in that image red circle text will be title that text will be replace should be name of the file

Comment: I fixed that image for you.

Comment: thank, are you get my point dear,this pdf file

Comment: *“According to my logic it should rename the file, but the output is not proper”* is just a lie isn't it. The code you have shown doesn't make any attempt to rename any files. All it does is update the `<page-count>` element in XML files according to the actual page count for the corresponding PDF, and I'm not certain that you have written even this. Basically you're trying to get your work done for free—hence your repeated plea to *"can you apply your code in my given code to solve problem because i am little bit confused."*.

Comment: sorry but i am actually confused,if you think i am tell lie then not need to help me,if really want to help then help,i think its right place to solve the problem but i am think wrong

Comment: Please accept the ans which you deem fit. The solution for question asked is already there. You cannot expect anyone to do beyond that

Comment: I am only ask for help, not beyond that but some extra smart people give me statement like that  "give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime ". if you not interested to give answer just say no.but not gives that kind of statement. you also give the solution or help not that kind of statement

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just open a PDF file and operate on it. It's different from a text file so it has to be parsed.
You can use [CAM::PDF](http://p3rl.org/CAM::PDF). It will convert your pdf to text which can be later analysed to get the title.

The links provided above covers enough stuff to get your job done. I am reproducing some relevant stuff here

```
use CAM::PDF;
my $pdf = CAM::PDF->new('test1.pdf');
$pageNum = 1
my $page1 = $pdf->getPageContent(pageNum);
```

The variable `page1` will have the contents of page specified by pageNum variable. Rest is a matter of extracting the required information.

If you find converting the entire pdf to text then you can use  [getpdftext.pl](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/CAM-PDF/bin/getpdftext.pl) which is a  part of CAM::PDF however that's inefficient compared to reading a single page.

Comment: thanks for information sharad,can you help me to improve my code

Comment: Extracting the text and grepping for the title sounds like a decent idea. I'm not sure about PDF::Parse though. It was last updated in 2000 and might not be able to work with current versions of the PDF standard, especially compressed files.

Comment: @sagarmore: go through the CAM::PDF documentation once and try it out. It has capability to read the page number you want and manipulate date in the page

Comment: And if the title of file is following a pattern (it looks like that), parsing that out will be very simple.

Comment: thanks for info.but its can applied on multiple file or not?

Comment: Yes. You will have to use the piece of code I have written on each file (except line 1 which needs to be written on top of the program).

Comment: can you applied that piece of code in my given code

Comment: @sharad can you apply your code in my given code to solve problem because i am little bit confused.

Comment: *give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime*

Comment: i am not a coding background,please help me

Answer (score 1):

PDFs usually have a bunch of metadata, among them is the document title. If you're lucky, you will find the desired PDF title in there. A Perl example using `PDF::API2` and its [info](https://metacpan.org/pod/PDF::API2#infohash-pdf-info-infohash) method:

```perl
use autodie;
use Modern::Perl;
use PDF::API2;

my $file     = '/your/sample/file.pdf';
my $pdf      = PDF::API2->open( $file );
my %pdf_info = $pdf->info;
my $title    = $pdf_info{Title};

my $renamed_dir = '/some/where/else/';
if ( $title ) {
    my $new_name = $renamed_dir . $title;
    if ( -f $new_name ) {
        warn "File $new_name already exists, move it out of the way!";
    } else {
        $pdf->saveas( $new_name );
    }
} else {
    warn "No title found in document info.";
}
```

If you need to use some part of the text, then you should convert it to text first. Since you failed to mention any OS restrictions you get a Debian/Ubuntu solution for that. First, install the package `poppler-utils`. Then use the freshly installed tool `pdftotext` to extract all the text from the PDF. It might be a good idea to use `pdftotext -layout`. From the resulting text you will have to grep/parse the line with your "title", and then use that to rename (or much safer: copy) the PDF.

Comment: I am assuming from the image posted that OP is not looking for title in "title" metadata but in the document's text

Comment: this line (eg SPE-180024-MS) its contain common text that is 

"MS" in every file that why i am applied grep command and replace it